# Difference between Fourier series on $(0,l)$ and Fourier series on $[0,l]$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series

I'm currently using Strauss's partial differential equations book and there is something that confuses me. The Fourier series of $f(x)=x$ on $(0,l)$ is not the same on $[0,l]$.

For $(0,l)$ the Fourier series is
$$x=\frac{2l}{\pi} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\text{sin}\left(\frac{n\pi x}{l}\right)$$
For $[0,l]$ the Fourier series is 
$$x=\frac{l}{2}-\frac{4l}{\pi^{2}}\sum_{n=1,3,5,...}\text{cos}\left(\frac{n\pi x}{l}\right)\frac{1}{n^{2}}$$

Why $(0,l)$ has sine series but $[0,l]$ has cosine series?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether you include the endpoints of the interval or not is immaterial.  There are [Fourier sine series and Fourier cosine series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_sine_and_cosine_series) on any interval.  The cosine series is
the full Fourier series of the function extended to $[-l, l]$ by $f(-x) = f(x)$ and then made periodic.
The sine series is the full Fourier series of the function extended to $[-l,l]$ by $f(-x) = -f(x)$ and then made periodic.

BTW: your cosine series should be
$$ \frac{l}{2} - \frac{4l}{\pi^2} \sum_{n=1,3,5,\ldots} \frac{\cos\left(\frac{n\pi x}{l}\right)}{n^2} $$

Comment: Thank you. I've corrected the mistake.